# Generate date sequence in T-SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql, date, select, recursive-query

In a record of purchases, I want to generate a sequence of +/-12 months out of a base date

```
Client Date 
Joe    2020-03-15
Maria  2019-11-01
```

so the desired outcome would be

```
Client Date 
Joe    2019-03-15
Joe    2019-04-15
.
.
.
Joe    2020-03-15
.
.
.
Joe    2021-02-15
Joe    2021-03-15
Maria  2018-11-01
Maria  2018-12-01
.
.
.
Maria  2019-11-01
.
.
.
Maria  2020-10-01
Maria  2020-11-01
```

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 2):

One option uses a recursive query:

```
with cte as (
    select client, dateadd(month, -12, date) date, 0 lvl from mytbale
    union all
    select client, dateadd(month, 1, date), lvl + 1 from cte where lvl < 24
)
select * from cte order by client, date
```

Comment: Gosh... don't use rCTEs (Recursive CTEs) for something like this even if there is a small number of rows.  The method causes a whole lot of resource usage and can pretty easily be beaten by a well written WHILE loop.  Please see the following article for more detail on the subject of resource usage for rCTEs (a form of "Hidden RBAR" and 3 methods that beat the tar out of it. https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/hidden-rbar-counting-with-recursive-ctes

Answer (score 2):

Just another option is an ad-hoc Tally Table in concert with a `CROSS JOIN`

**Example**

```
Select A.Client
      ,[Date] = date,DateAdd(MONTH,N,[Date])
 From  YourTable A
 Cross Join  ( Select Top (12+1) N=-1+Row_Number() Over (Order By (Select Null)) From  master..spt_values n1)  B
```

**Returns**

```
Client  Date
Joe     2020-03-15
Joe     2020-04-15
Joe     2020-05-15
Joe     2020-06-15
Joe     2020-07-15
Joe     2020-08-15
Joe     2020-09-15
Joe     2020-10-15
Joe     2020-11-15
Joe     2020-12-15
Joe     2021-01-15
Joe     2021-02-15
Joe     2021-03-15
Maria   2019-11-01
Maria   2019-12-01
Maria   2020-01-01
Maria   2020-02-01
Maria   2020-03-01
Maria   2020-04-01
Maria   2020-05-01
Maria   2020-06-01
Maria   2020-07-01
Maria   2020-08-01
Maria   2020-09-01
Maria   2020-10-01
Maria   2020-11-01
```

**EDIT:** If you want +/- 12 months, just a small tweak is required

```
 ...
 Cross Join  ( Select Top (24+1) N=-13+Row_Number() Over (Order By (Select Null)) From  master..spt_values n1)  B
```

Comment: Note: OP appears to want the last 12 and next 12 months, as can be seen in their sample data (I guess that’s what they mean by *+/- 12 months*).

Comment: @GMB I did see that, but I was confused by the desired results.   Either way, it would be a small matter with a little math  :)

Comment: Yes that’s a simple change to the query indeed.

Comment: What happens if a leap year is included in the -12 months?

Comment: @JeffModen Not an issue.  If the base date was Feb 29 the -12 would default to Feb 28.    Also regarding your comment in support of the WHILE loop, I respectfully disagree.  Loops should be avoided when possible.

Comment: Disregard my last.  For some reason, I thought the OP wanted an output by day rather than by month,  Since it's by month, days aren't going to matter.

Comment: p.s.  You didn't understand what I meant... It totally agree that a WHILE loop should be avoided at all costs for things of this nature,.  My point was that an rCTE is as bad or worse than a WHILE Loop and should also be avoided at all costs for the incremental generation of numbers.

Comment: @JeffModen Got it.  This I agree with :)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a slightly different solution that uses the essence of a Tally table.  The reason why I'm posting it is because a lot of people aren't allowed to use things in the master database by their DBAs and also because needing a sequence of values is a very common thing.  The following method also causes no Logical Reads in the generation of the sequence.

To wit, the "Tally Table" has frequently been referred to as the "Swiss Army Knife" of T-SQL.  It's so important that Erland Sommarskog requested a built in sequence generator though MS "CONNECT" (the old name for "Feedback") more than a decade ago.  Unfortunately, MS has done nothing other than keep the request open for more than a decade.

With that in mind, here's my rendition of Itzik Ben-Gan's fine work to create such a function.  It very intentionally can only start at "0" or "1" but can go up to (actually past) any positive INT value you might need.  If you need it to start at a different number than "0" or "1", a simple bit of integer math outside of the function will make it happen.  The reason why I didn't build that capability into the function is because sequences starting at "0" or "1" are the most common usage and I didn't want to penalize performance even by a millisecond or two because of the extreme usage that I put this function through.

Here's the function... everyone should have something like it either in every database or in a "utility" database that the general public can use.

```
 CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnTally]
/**********************************************************************************************************************
 Purpose:
 Return a column of BIGINTs from @ZeroOrOne up to and including @MaxN with a max value of 10 Quadrillion.

 Usage:
--===== Syntax example
 SELECT t.N
   FROM dbo.fnTally(@ZeroOrOne,@MaxN) t
;
 @ZeroOrOne will internally conver to a 1 for any number other than 0 and a 0 for a 0.
 @MaxN has an operational domain from 0 to 4,294,967,296. Silent truncation occurs for larger numbers.

 Please see the following notes for other important information

 Notes:
 1. This code works for SQL Server 2008 and up.
 2. Based on Itzik Ben-Gan's cascading CTE (cCTE) method for creating a "readless" Tally Table source of BIGINTs.
    Refer to the following URL for how it works.
    https://www.itprotoday.com/sql-server/virtual-auxiliary-table-numbers
 3. To start a sequence at 0, @ZeroOrOne must be 0. Any other value that's convertable to the BIT data-type
    will cause the sequence to start at 1.
 4. If @ZeroOrOne = 1 and @MaxN = 0, no rows will be returned.
 5. If @MaxN is negative or NULL, a "TOP" error will be returned.
 6. @MaxN must be a positive number from >= the value of @ZeroOrOne up to and including 4,294,967,296. If a larger
    number is used, the function will silently truncate after that max. If you actually need a sequence with that many
    or more values, you should consider using a different tool. ;-)
 7. There will be a substantial reduction in performance if "N" is sorted in descending order.  If a descending sort is
    required, use code similar to the following. Performance will decrease by about 27% but it's still very fast 
    especially compared with just doing a simple descending sort on "N", which is about 20 times slower.
    If @ZeroOrOne is a 0, in this case, remove the "+1" from the code.

    DECLARE @MaxN BIGINT; 
     SELECT @MaxN = 1000;
     SELECT DescendingN = @MaxN-N+1 
       FROM dbo.fnTally(1,@MaxN);

 8. There is no performance penalty for sorting "N" in ascending order because the output is implicity sorted by
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
 9. This will return 1-10,000,000 to a bit-bucket variable in about 986ms.
    This will return 0-10,000,000 to a bit-bucket variable in about 1091ms.
    This will return 1-4,294,967,296 to a bit-bucket variable in about 9:12( mi:ss).

 Revision History:
 Rev 00 - Unknown     - Jeff Moden 
        - Initial creation with error handling for @MaxN.
 Rev 01 - 09 Feb 2013 - Jeff Moden 
        - Modified to start at 0 or 1.
 Rev 02 - 16 May 2013 - Jeff Moden 
        - Removed error handling for @MaxN because of exceptional cases.
 Rev 03 - 07 Sep 2013 - Jeff Moden 
        - Change the max for @MaxN from 10 Billion to 10 Quadrillion to support an experiment. 
          This will also make it much more difficult for someone to actually get silent truncation in the future.
 Rev 04 - 04 Aug 2019 - Jeff Moden
        - Enhance performance by making the first CTE provide 256 values instead of 10, which limits the number of
          CrossJoins to just 2. Notice that this changes the maximum range of values to "just" 4,294,967,296, which
          is the entire range for INT and just happens to be an even power of 256. Because of the use of the VALUES
          clause, this code is "only" compatible with SQLServer 2008 and above.
        - Update old link from "SQLMag" to "ITPro". Same famous original article, just a different link because they
          changed the name of the company (twice, actually).
        - Update the flower box notes with the other changes.
**********************************************************************************************************************/
        (@ZeroOrOne BIT, @MaxN BIGINT)
RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING AS 
 RETURN WITH
  H2(N) AS ( SELECT 1 
               FROM (VALUES
                     (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)
                    ,(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)
                    ,(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)
                    ,(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)
                    ,(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)
                    ,(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)
                    ,(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)
                    ,(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)
                    ,(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)
                    ,(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)
                    ,(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)
                    ,(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)
                    ,(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)
                    ,(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)
                    ,(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)
                    ,(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)
                    )V(N))            --16^2 or 256 rows
, H4(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM H2 a, H2 b) --16^4 or 65,536 rows
, H8(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM H4 a, H4 b) --16^8 or 4,294,967,296 rows
            SELECT N = 0 WHERE @ZeroOrOne = 0 UNION ALL
            SELECT TOP(@MaxN)
                   N = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY N)
              FROM H8
;
```

p.s.  I normally don't use "Hungarian-Notation" for objects but I also have a Tally Table and you can't have two objects with the same name.

Once you have something like that, problems that require sequences of numbers become easy, fast, and inexpensive resource-wise.  For example, here's how I would code the solution to the OP's problem using this function.

```
--===== Solve the problem using the fnTally function as a numeric sequence generator starting
     -- at 0 and ending at the +/- 12 month differences for each Client's base date.
DECLARE @OffsetMonths INT = 12 --Just to make it a bit more flexible
;
 SELECT  d.Client
        ,[Date] = DATEADD(mm,t.N-@OffsetMonths,d.[Date])
   FROM #TestTable d
  CROSS APPLY dbo.fnTally(0,@OffsetMonths*2) t
  ORDER BY d.Client,[Date]
;
```

If you want to test that code, here's what I built for a test table.

```
--===== Create and populate a test table.
     -- This is NOT a part of the solution.
     -- We're just creating test data here.
   DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #TestTable
;
 CREATE TABLE #TestTable
        (
         Client VARCHAR(20)
        ,[Date] DATE
        )
;
 INSERT INTO #TestTable
        (Client,[Date])
 VALUES  ('Joe','2020-03-15')
        ,('Maria','2019-11-01')
;
```

If you'd like to know more about how "Tally Tables" and related functions work, here's a link to my article, which is much too long to post here.

[The "Numbers" or "Tally" Table: What it is and how it replaces a loop](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/the-numbers-or-tally-table-what-it-is-and-how-it-replaces-a-loop-1)