# Duplicating rows in Spark SQL when values are not consecutive?

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a table with columns datetime and quantity that are being used to track time spent to finish a workflow.

| datetime | quantity |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-01-01 14:05 | 5 |
| 2023-01-01 14:12 | 12 |
| 2023-01-01 14:13 | 13 |
| 2023-01-01 14:20 | 17 |

I want to duplicate the datetime rows when the lead quantity is not a consecutive value so that each distinct quantity number has a datetime value assigned to it. Goal table below:

| datetime | quantity |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-01-01 14:05 | 1 |
| 2023-01-01 14:05 | 2 |
| 2023-01-01 14:05 | 3 |
| 2023-01-01 14:05 | 4 |
| 2023-01-01 14:05 | 5 |
| 2023-01-01 14:12 | 6 |
| 2023-01-01 14:12 | 7 |
| 2023-01-01 14:12 | 8 |
| 2023-01-01 14:12 | 9 |
| 2023-01-01 14:12 | 10 |
| 2023-01-01 14:12 | 11 |
| 2023-01-01 14:12 | 12 |
| 2023-01-01 14:13 | 13 |
| 2023-01-01 14:20 | 14 |
| 2023-01-01 14:20 | 15 |
| 2023-01-01 14:20 | 16 |
| 2023-01-01 14:20 | 17 |

I haven't been able to find a way to duplicate datetime values for growing quantity figures.

So far I'm stuck and any basic attempts of filling in the values have been unsuccessful.

Comment: What to think of the answers?

Answer (score 1):

(ANSI SQL in general and) T-SQL in particular does provide for

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    (date_time datetime, quantity int)
;
    
INSERT INTO Table1
    (date_time, quantity)
VALUES
    ('2023-01-01 14:05:00', 5),
    ('2023-01-01 14:12:00', 12),
    ('2023-01-01 14:13:00', 13),
    ('2023-01-01 14:20:00', 17)
;

;with
List0(quantity) as (
  select
    1
  union all
  select
    quantity + 1
  from List0
  where quantity < 10000
),
List1a as (
  select top 1000000
    t1.date_time,
    l0.quantity
  from List0 l0
  left join Table1 t1
    on t1.quantity = l0.quantity
  order by l0.quantity
),
List1 as (
  select top 1000000
    (select date_time
     from Table1
     where quantity = (select min(quantity)
                       from Table1
                       where quantity >= l0.quantity)
    ) as date_time,
    l0.quantity
  from List0 l0
  left join Table1 t1
    on t1.quantity = l0.quantity
  order by l0.quantity
)
select
--  * from List0
  * from List1a
--  * from List1 where quantity <= (select max(quantity) from Table1)
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 10000)
;
```

This comes with some flexibility and some limitations.

Not sure, it works this way in Apache Spark - and for your actual needs.

However, instead of the recursive CTE (*List0*) you could either use a system table with a sufficient number of consecutive IDs or generate a number table.

See it in action: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/25be9/4).

#### How does it work?

NB: For illustration purposes, *List1a* has been added.

- First, some kind of number table is needed to get the full sequence of required values. This is here the purpose of *List0*. (Technically, there is no need to name its column after the one in the actual data. And it has far more rows than required for the sample data - just to stress its generic nature.)
- *List1a* demonstrates how the `LEFT JOIN` fills the gaps in the original data. But all rows with no data for *date_time* come back with just *null*.
- The sub-`SELECT` in the `SELECT` of *List1* pulls the 'next available' *date_time* from *Table1* in order to fill the gaps.
- `top 1000000` is needed for SQL Server to 'allow' the `order by` inside a CTE. (Routinely, I pick the million - as it usually exceeds by far the number of expected rows...)
- `OPTION (MAXRECURSION 10000)` moves the recursion limit for *List0* up from the standard value 100.

Please comment, if and as this requires adjustment / further detail.

---

Edit:
@thebluephantom kindly pointed out, Spark not to feature recursive queries.

- [Generate date sequence in T-SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62221569/generate-date-sequence-in-t-sql)
- [How to generate a range of numbers between two numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21425546/how-to-generate-a-range-of-numbers-between-two-numbers)

are just two discussions for T-SQL / SQL for obtaining sequences.

[SparkSQL on pyspark: how to generate time series?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43141671/sparksql-on-pyspark-how-to-generate-time-series)
is focussing on Spark.

My objective was to give a working example, how the issue at hand can be resolved... Unfortunately, I can't address the Spark specifics.

Comment: It is about Spark which has no recursive queries.

Comment: See my answer, not really a Spark suited thing.

Comment: @Abecee Thank you for the solution but can you please explain the logic because i try to break into pieces and is not easy to understand the logic.
I use Sql Server 2022.
Thank you

Comment: @Florin: Some detail has been added. Are there specific aspects, that need more detail? You might want to play with the updated Fiddle...

Answer (score 0):

This is a Spark / Scala example. My own data, you need to tailor to yours.

This question shows some issues with Spark when executed at scale. The scale is not stated in the question.

Databricks stated that RANGE optimization could help. https://docs.databricks.com/optimizations/range-join.html I was not convinced.

Coding for small scale.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{StructField,StructType,IntegerType, ArrayType, LongType}

// 1. Gen data in quick, but not best manner. You can tailor otherwise. Renamed your column latterly.
val df = Seq( ( "A",  5), ( "B", 12), ( "C", 13 ), ( "D", 17) ).toDF("key" ,"qty")

// Some manipulation of data first.
val df2 = df.withColumn("accum_qty", col("qty").cast("long")).drop("qty") // If not already Long.
val rddWithZip = df2.rdd.zipWithIndex
val newSchema = StructType(df2.schema.fields ++ Array(StructField("rowid", LongType, false)))
val df3 =  spark.createDataFrame(rddWithZip.map{ case (row, index) => Row.fromSeq(row.toSeq ++ Array(index))}, newSchema)

// 2. Get last Row in Dataframe and the accum_qty from that. 2 approaches shown, latter simpler.
// val max_accum_qty = df2.reduce { (a, b) => if (a.getAs[Long]("accum_qty") > b.getAs[Long]("accum_qty")) a else b 
//                               } match {case Row(key:String,accum_qty:Long) => (accum_qty)}
val max_accum_qty = df2.select(max("accum_qty")).as[Long].head()

// 3. Make a range DF. A helper table.
val dfRn = spark.range(max_accum_qty).withColumn("lkp", col("id") + 1).drop("id")

// 4. Now we have base data and need to restrict joining later, with some extra data. If Serialization error, add transient. I am using a Notebook, so may not alwas show up. No natural partition by possibility!
val w = org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window.orderBy("rowid")  
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.lag
val df4 = df3.withColumn("accum_qty_prev_temp", lag("accum_qty", 1, 0).over(w)).withColumn("accum_qty_prev", col("accum_qty_prev_temp") + 1).drop("accum_qty_prev_temp", "rowid")

// 5. Actual JOIN. Bad performance and may only work with small volumes, e.g. OOM errors.
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{StructField,StructType,IntegerType, ArrayType, LongType}

val res = df4.join(dfRn, (  df4("accum_qty_prev") <= dfRn("lkp") && df4("accum_qty") >= dfRn("lkp" )),"inner")   //.explain(false)
res.show(false)

// 6. Add your own select clause...
```